# testautomation - Can´t test game on android screen

Tags: java, android, testing, automation, appium

That i want to do is to "click"/"touch" on a android screen through images because i want to test a game and this game don't have any xpath. 
If i cant use image recognition then I at least want to "click" on the screen using coordinates.

But none of these options have worked for me so far. 
This far has i come. Now i using Appium Driver.

USING IMAGE RECOGNITION ON DESKTOP:

public void playGame() throws InterruptedException, FindFailed {

```
    Screen screen = new Screen();
    String imageLibrary = "src/main/resources/automated-tests/images/";
    String skipIntro = imageLibrary + "JackAndTheBeanstalk/skip.PNG";
    String skipInfo = imageLibrary + "JackAndTheBeanstalk/continue.PNG";
    String bet = imageLibrary + "JackAndTheBeanstalk/increaseStakes.PNG";
    String play = imageLibrary + "JackAndTheBeanstalk/play.PNG";
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    if (screen.exists(new Pattern(skipIntro).similar((float) 0.8)) != null) {
        System.out.println("Start playing Jack and the beanstalk");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        screen.click(new Pattern(skipIntro).similar((float) 0.8));
        screen.click(new Pattern(skipIntro).similar((float) 0.8));
        screen.click(new Pattern(skipInfo).similar((float) 0.8));
        screen.click(new Pattern(bet).similar((float) 0.8));
        screen.click(new Pattern(play).similar((float)0.8));
    }
}
```

This image recognition is working fine on desktop. My goal is to do this but on android! But the click method don´t work on android, only desktop. I have heard that you can use tap, performTouchAction and press instead but i don´t know how to use them.

USING PRESS ON ANDROID:

TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
            action.press(10, 0).moveTo(22,33).release().perform();

The problem here is that i don´t know how to get the RIGHT coordinates for android.

Have anyone tried to test automate mobile games/or something similar on android or used image recognition on android or used coordinates on android? Or have you used a different tactic to test automate on android or an other device?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what library you are using for image recognition (what do you import to use `Screen` class?).

But its obvious, that *only Appium is not enough* to test it.

You can research for `Appium + Sikuli API` or `Appium+OpenCV` prototypes.

Several links so far:

[Appium+Sikuli](https://medium.com/@SimonKaz/appium-with-image-recognition-17a92abaa23d)

[Appium+OpenCV+Akaze](https://bitbar.com/how-to-use-image-recognition-for-mobile-app-and-game-testing/)

Comment: I using import org.sikuli.script.Screen; but in the both links the "tap" function don´t work. So im a bit confused how to correctly use image recognition with Appium

Comment: Check the links I posted, first one is how to use Sikuli API + Appium. There is no exact answer for your question as it is more general and for each game app there might be different image recognition tool is the best option. Try it out based links I posted and let me know if anything works for you.